# Запятая после слова "конечно" не ставится, если..?

Tags: пунктуация

При употреблении в ответной реплике, произносимой тоном уверенности, убежденности, слово «конечно» может не обособляться: «Это правда?» – «Конечно правда!»

- -Конечно нет!  /  - Конечно да!   /  - Конечно приеду!
- Ах, Фунтик, ты со мной согласен?
- Конечно да, конечно да, конечно ДА!

В  тексте песни из м/ф "Приключения поросенка Фунтика" запятые между "конечно" и "да" стоят. Значит, можно ставить и не ставить по решению автора?

А если:

Конечно же нет! /  Уж конечно нет! / Я конечно бы тоже поехал  отдыхать в Сочи, но нет времени.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот что говорят справочники.

Слово конечно, произносимое тоном уверенности, убежденности, приобретает значение утвердительной частицы и запятыми не выделяется: Конечно правда!; Конечно же это так; Я конечно бы пришёл, если бы меня заранее предупредили. Ср.:

— Вы согласны?

— Только в принципе, конечно (‘разумеется’).

— Но в принципе вы согласны? 
— Вы конечно же прочитаете эту книгу («обязательно», значение усиления);

Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь. Д.Э. Академический справочник.

То же на Грамма.ру. [Грамма.ру. Вводные слова. стр.5](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.36)

Но. 2. Утвердительная частица ***(в ответной реплике). То же, что «да».*** Обособляется или оформляется как отдельное предложение.

В Соловце будете останавливаться?» – cпросил горбоносый. «Конечно, – сказал я. – Я в Соловец и еду». А. и Б. Стругацкие, Понедельник начинается в субботу. «Конечно, да, – грустно отвечал он. – Но как я скучаю без него, если бы вы знали!» В. Каверин, Два капитана.

@ Не выделяется знаками препинания слово «конечно» в начале ответной реплики, произносимой тоном уверенности, убеждённости: ***Конечно же это так! Конечно правда!***
[Запятание трудных слов и выражений.](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=761.BJleDGj1eo8GIiS-Xor-wf2mirVUlWhJFyyvuh0BcpfkQFmxgiaFmvy02ls4K4MGpHJ0MG9sVyn3OVJMciRSYqACe-EB2TFs5ZY4fJ_8GpBeGbLEwfHQAhlkshA0xvc9.61d89ebed317a59a4f37c2ba59ffe3df13be4d85&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9bb4iM1VPfe4W5x0C0-qwflIRTTifi6VAA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxbzRZRkExTE1SekJnZXNpMFJkZnhnbnJaYk9RdnlHTmVNckFaMHQ1YWpOZXFoWE9wbFZCSWZPV1pGSjlkWFRramo5dUJfWnN3czEzLTVYcTdFbFJmdC1tVEpmYUpjcll3clNoZmFyZ29zcVk&b64e=2&sign=eec78cd63ea93f29ecf78907277bb958&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5Hyx_fyvalFPA9KI5rmKu0WS7bRgCElMxpwHW8czAf5ulH3IZ7RVvKV6sxebzSUfkDBVjrqNdB1Rqv2AtD0i-OvtkZYiWawBzydoDiCaapmo4nwu7xFj-iRPzt_JsJdhqqvHroaRH0pREg1lagknVgGo9pl5cnG3ZQwRBg07t2rHP1Jg-qEiuW_4N9cXV33mbQs-9zpF0C1Q&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHpMQ80108_UCTdwuV_bvPyfSQ3Wu39WHEQuhu8kJcY3-9D4MQJ-e8QPe2LpxKM75PId1niBvBOIrWVUwzkDC7igftkTCGECRDGKeoUeqgy1F1SQl7DiGxTOwXJte8dPI7y1Xt4EO_zn9Y1uTAbgH12BK24DC5lZPI9-CIBBNpYNDfF9Dei_IdfaDo9JGUs1H_FkK4PlwGFHzFsDMCjmnCviISOlH-HmZdbPpX7hRIDDv0Bv2aoAHhyYgduIg0jWzpRojQN_ARxMABvpO2bTj4Yk4RacM2cO5Tesz5hc-5kP1e6KRCe8otXtC30_gRaiUKxHNJsY_fQCN&l10n=ru&cts=1437896010496&mc=3.59057108125986)

Материал на сайте взят из справочника на Грамота.ру. Но вот что странно. Второй пункт в справочники отсутствует.

Answer (score 3):

*Конечно* – вводное слово и выделяется запятыми по общему правилу. У Розенталя сказано: «Слово *конечно* **ОБЫЧНО выделяется запятыми** в качестве вводного: *Конечно, много значит привычка.* Но **ИНОГДА** слово *конечно*, **произносимое тоном уверенности**, приобретает **значение утвердительной частицы** и пунктуационно не выделяется: *Конечно правда!*»

Некоторые делают из этого ложный вывод: если к слову *конечно* присоединяется частица (например, *же*), вводное слово «очастичивается», а потому *конечно же* запятыми точно не выделяется.

Правило нужно понимать так: *конечно* превращается в частицу в начале ответной реплики (то есть когда есть диалог), и то в том случае, если на него падает ударение.

Сравните:
*«Это правда?» – «Конечно правда!»* (ударение на конечно).

*«Это правда?» – «Конечно, это правда!»* (ударение на правда).

Но можно и так: *«Это правда?» – «Конечно, правда!»* (ударение на правда).

Грамота.ру в своем справочнике пишет: "При употреблении в ответной реплике, произносимой тоном уверенности, убежденности, слово «конечно» **может не обособляться**: «Это правда?» – «Конечно правда!»

То есть может и обособляться. Это вопрос тонкий, интонационный. Нет строгого правила о том, что не обособляется при определенных условиях. Есть оговорка, что может не обособляться.

Answer (score 2):

GRAMOTA.RU:

КОНЕЧНО, вводное слово

Употребляется для выражения уверенности говорящего в истинности высказывания; то же, что «несомненно, разумеется, действительно».

> *Сергей Петрович воспитания, **конечно**, не получил, по-французски не
>   говорит; но он, воля ваша, приятный человек.* И. Тургенев, Дворянское
>   гнездо. *Дорогой читатель! Вы уже, **конечно**, обратили внимание на
>   то, что боец последнего года службы Иван Чонкин был маленького роста,
>   кривоногий, да еще и с красными ушами.* В. Войнович, Жизнь и
>   необычайные приключения солдата Ивана Чонкина. *Стишки, **конечно**,
>   дрянь, но с формальной точки зрения и они тоже поэзия.* Б. Акунин,
>   Внеклассное чтение.

@ ***При употреблении в ответной реплике, произносимой тоном уверенности, убежденности, слово «конечно» может не обособляться:*** «Это правда?» – «**Конечно** правда!»

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно понял, то все сводится к тому, что решение о наличии или отсутствии запятых, обособляющих слово «конечно», должно приниматься автором исходя исключительно из конкретной смысловой нагрузки самой фразы, смысл которой он и хочет донести с ее помощью, а, следовательно, также самих роли роли и места в ней данного слова: если хочешь его выделить как «смысловое ударение во фразе», тем самым именно на нем акцентировав все внимание читателя, выразив тем самым «правильную», изначально задуманную интонационную окраску всему смыслу выраженной мысли - смело обособляй! А ежели в сути мысли, выраженной в предложении, «конечно» не играет никакой значимой роли для восприятия смысла и присутствует во фразе лишь в виде её стилистического украшения и придания лексического «объема», синонимической «сочности» и красоты, и не более того (то есть, можно и вовсе смело обойтись и без «конечно» или легко заменить его смысловым синонимом) - в таком случае можно это слово и вовсе не выделять... Так что ли получается, если в общем?!...‍♂️ 
   Или если оно играет важную роль в смысловом значении фразы, когда есть уверенность в сказанном ( - «Правда?», - «Конечно (146%, стопудово, зуб даю, *ля буду... и т.д.) да!») оно запятыми не выделяется, тем самым подчеркивая свою неразрывность ради передачи истинного смысла в контексте основного изречения, весьма заметно его при этом усиливая. 
   А при задаче поставить во фразе явный смысловой акцент в виде сарказма, сомнения или недоверия к обстоятельствам или словам самого контекста фразы, получается, оно всегда будет обособляться? («Все это, конечно, прекрасно, но может стоит уже, наконец, повзрослеть?»)