# Запятая после "конечно" (1)

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли запятая после "конечно" в таком предложении?

**Я конечно понимаю, что от моих слов ничего не изменится, но всё-таки...**

Comment: @slava1947 Мне теперь свой ответ тоже менять? Я сделала правку и указала на ошибку в ответе.

Comment: Сказать по правде, я Вашего ответа при правке не увидел. Выше него стоял ответ Жасмин, в котором эта запятая была проставлена, но акцента на её отсутствии у автора вопроса в ответе Жасмин не было обозначено, и потому её  ответу моя правка, вроде бы, не должна была навредить. Что касается Вашего ответа... Подскажите, что мне сделать, я исполню.

Comment: Да бог с Вами — _я исполню_! Просто лишний раз авторское предложение я стараюсь не трогать. Оставим как есть. P.S. У Jasmin в первоначальном ответе запятой не было, она появилась позже, в результате правки.

Answer (score 6):

**конечно**

1. ***Вводное слово***
   Вы используете слово **конечно**, чтобы подчеркнуть уверенность в том, что вы говорите. Имеет значение: несомненно, безусловно, разумеется, без сомнения.
   Выделяется с двух сторон запятыми:
   *Она, конечно, доверяла мне. Конечно, никто не знал о нашем договоре.*
2. ***В знач. утвердительной частицы***
   Вы говорите **конечно**, когда соглашаетесь с тем, что только что сказал ваш собеседник.
   При уверенном и убеждённом тоне слово «конечно» может не обособляться:

*«Это правда?» – «Конечно правда!»*

*— Он собирается извиниться перед нами?

— Конечно, нет!*

[**КОНЕЧНО**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_363)

В Вашем предложении "конечно" — это вводное слово, и запятая необходима не только *после* "конечно", но и *перед* ним. Кроме того, запятая нужна и перед "что":

**Я, конечно, понимаю, что от моих слов ничего не изменится, но всё-таки...**

Некоторые мнения и особенности пунктуации можно посмотреть [**здесь**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417129/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8) и [**здесь**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE).

Comment: Замечательный ответ.

Comment: Весьма признательна.

Answer (score 3):

Я, конечно,  понимаю, что от моих слов ничего не изменится,но всё-таки..

Это вводное слово со значением "разумеется, несомненно", которое обособляется.

В роли частицы может не обособляться в ответной реплике: Ты это понимаешь? – Конечно понимаю.

Comment: Спасибо большое